# juggernaut error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, juggernaut

i am trying to experiment with Juggernaut plugin using chat_sandbox example.

i get this error message

```
Juggernaut: There has been an error connecting on 127.0.0.1:5001
```

I have no idea what it means.

my juggernaut.yml is as follows

```
:hosts:
  - :port: 5001
    :host: 127.0.0.1
    :public_host: 127.0.0.1
    :public_port: 5001
    # :secret_key: your_secret_key
    # :environment: :development
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you started juggernaut?

```
juggernaut -c juggernaut.yml
```

Then juggernaut will write something like `Starting Juggernaut server 0.5.8 on port: 5001...` or will return an error.